# Appending a generator class object to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a feature dataset that contains many fruits and the label tells with a logistic probability whether one is an apple or not using tensorflow.
However I can't seem to add the predicted data to the original dataframe.

```
    predictions = DNN_classifier.predict(input_fn=is_apple_ds)
```

This returns a generator class object and if I create a column and add it to the original dataframe it just says "generator class object at some address"

I instead want to add a column to the original dataframe that would give the actual predicted values instead of this

Edit:
My question simply is to how to extract all the values from a generator object and add it to a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `tensorflow` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier#predict) `predict()` will `yield` each predicition. This is why you get a generator object.

---

```
def generate_sequence():
    for x in range(0,10):
        yield x

generated_sequence = generate_sequence()
```

---

```
>> print(generated_sequence)
<generator object generate_sequence at 0x7fdc31f23990>
```

---

You can put a generator object into a `DataFrame` by converting it to a `list` or by simply calling `pd.DataFrame()` with it.

```
>> list(generated_sequence)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>> pd.DataFrame(generated_sequence)

0
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
```

Comment: It returns a list of dictionaries each like this: `{'logits': array([-5.0688373e-05], dtype=float32), 'logistic': array([0.49998736], dtype=float32), 'probabilities': array([0.5000127 , 0.49998736], dtype=float32), 'class_ids': array([0]), 'classes': array([b'0'], dtype=object)}` , How come they are all the same?

Comment: You will have to look at what `predict()` yields and what you want from that result.